# Checking the value of a typedef alias

Tags: macros, switch-statement, signal-processing, typedef, numeric

I'm trying to write some DSP code that will need to run in both floating and fixed point environments (the numeric type will be determined at compile time).  I'd like to alias the particular numeric type using either a Macro or a typedef.  Multiplication, division and other math functions will vary considerably in implementation depending on the numeric type, so I'll need some sort of switch to determine whether to include certain headers and perhaps alter the implementation based on the numeric type.

I'll give a short code snippet as an example ...

```
typedef samp_t float;
// or #define samp_t float (bad naming practice?)

// An alternative in fixed point
samp_t multiply_samp_t(samp_t a, samp_t b){
   return a*b;
}

/* typedef samp_t int;
#define RADIX 24
samp_t multiply_samp_t(samp_t a, samp_t b){
   return (samp_t) ((long) a)*((long) b) >> RADIX);
}
*/

void main(void){
  samp_t a,b,c;
   a = 15;
   b = 27;
   c = multiply_samp_t(a,b);
}
```

So, how would one switch between the two different multiplications functions based on samp_t's type?  Any recommendations or suggestions are welcome. 
Thanks!
-Brant

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of choosing the functions corresponding to the data type at compile time:

```
#define SYSTEM_FLOAT 0
#define SYSTEM_INT 1

// main selection
#define TYPE_SYSTEM FLOAT

#if TYPE_SYSTEM == SYSTEM_FLOAT
  #define SAMP_T float
  #define mult_samp_t   mult_samp_t_float
#elif TYPE_SYSTEM == SYSTEM_INT
  #define SAMP_T int
  #define mult_samp_t   mult_samp_t_int
#elif ...
#endif

void main(void){
  SAMP_T a,b,c;
   a = 15;
   b = 27;
   c = mult_samp_t(a,b);
}
```

Somewhere in the code you must define:

```
float mult_samp_t_float(float a, float b)
{ 
  ...
  return a float;
}

float mult_samp_t_int(int a, int b)
{ 
  ...
  return an int;
}
```

That is, the type system you select will set the entire functions set you are going to use.
I still recommend, though, to use this scheme only if you can't do with runtime selection and function, because the way I presented here makes the code harder to debug (although I never had problems with it in the past).

(I encountered much worse things in code of professional OS :-) )

Comment: Thanks!  That gives me a rough idea of how to proceed.  I'd like to see a typedef version if such a thing exists, although I doubt it does since it's impossible (as far as I know) to check the existance of a typedef.